# Device rotation animation won't work in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, animation, screen-rotation

I have the following problem, searched in several places, but I can't find the solution, since I added some lines of code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the `AppDelegate`, to determine which View Controller will be launched at the beginning and to load Arrays with data saved before closing the App, That when rotating the device, in the simulator or in my iPhone, doesn't generate an animation when rotating.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 252/255.0, green: 140.0/255.0, blue: 90.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
    UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 252/255.0, green: 140.0/255.0, blue: 90.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    ...
}
```

Here the GIF:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Auto-rotation Animation by Device Orientation

### Problem

- iOS 11 : working
- iOS 9, 10 : not working

### Solution

> If you have 'Main Interface' and custom window setting in `AppDelegate`, DELETE one.

I solved this problem by deleting 'Target - General - Main Interface'. (Set it blank.)
But, still I don't know why this problem happened by setting main interface.